# SWT Combo resize dropdown list (show more items)

Tags: java, combobox, resize, swt, dropdown

my SWT Combo has a lot of items and the dropdownlist always shows only 5 items at the same time. (yes I can scroll up and down to see all the other items)

I want the dropdown list to show more items at the same time e.g. 10 items at the same time.

How can I make the dropdown list, to show more items at the same time?
Has anyone an example?
Thanks
Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `Combo` `setVisibleItemCount(int count)` method to set the number of items that are shown.

Note that the JavaDoc says:

> This operation is a hint and is not supported on platforms that do not
>   have this concept.

So it may not work on all platforms.

Alternatively use the `CCombo` control which also has a `setVisibleItemCount` that does work on all platforms.